# Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS' when I check SentryIO

Tags: sql-server

The code below is executing successfully in SQL Server but I am getting an error

`> Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'`

when I check SentryIO. Any idea why?

```
UPDATE uldd_rule_codes 
SET
    rule_logic = 'data_Master.[job id] = ''''6033'''' and data_miscloaninformation.Calculated_Indicator_FICO < ''''660'''' and data_miscloaninformation.[Original Lock Date] BETWEEN CAST (''''2020-06-03'''' AS DATE) and CAST(''''2020-06-14'''' AS DATE) and data_master.[Pool Number] not like ''''3%'''' AND data_master.[loan type] in (''''2'''',''''3'''',''''5'''') and data_miscreportinginformation.sub_channel not in (''''Cal-HFA'''',''''Del-HFA'''',''''Den-HFA'''',''''Phx-HFA'''',''''Tex-HFA'''',''''Wash-HFA'''')'
WHERE 
    rule_id = 12;
```

Comment: Why is all that code wrapped like that? Is this a dynamic statement? The above won't error a t all, as it's incomplete. Supply us with a [mre].

Comment: The code is used to update the rule_logic in a table that controls when a data check is fired. Below is the entire statement if that helps. This is the format we need to update data in the table.

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put stuff that shou;d be in the question in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` statement will run just fine as is--it's not doing any sytax work. However, you have too many single-ticks surrounding your values which is causing the exception upon execution.

Consider the following from your question:

```
DECLARE @rule VARCHAR(255) = 'SELECT CAST(''''2020-06-14'''' AS DATE)';
EXEC ( @rule );
```

When executed returns:

```
Incorrect syntax near '2020'.
```

However, removing the extra single-ticks around the date vaule:

```
DECLARE @rule VARCHAR(255) = 'SELECT CAST(''2020-06-14'' AS DATE)';
EXEC ( @rule );
```

Returns

```
2020-06-14
```

**Quick note/update:**

If a value is a known numeric, don't wrap it in quotes.

For instance:

```
data_Master.[job id] = ''''6033'''' and
```

If **[job_id]** is a numeric value, you should have this as:

```
data_Master.[job id] = 6033 and
```

Otherwise SQL Server needs to do an implicit conversion of the value which can lead to performance issues.